# Etwas Komisches in der ersten Position

Tags: sentence-structure

Ein paar Sätze aus *Parfum* von Patrick Süskind. Ich konzentriere mich gerade auf den zweiten:

> Grenouille hatte die Flasche abgesetzt, die mit Parfum benetzte Hand
> vom Hals genommen und an seinem Rocksaum abgewischt. **Ein, zwei Schritt
> zurück, das linkische Zusammenklappen seines Körpers unter Baldinis
> Standpauke schlugen genügend Wellen in der Luft, um den neugeschaffnen
> Duft ringsum zu verbreiten.**

Ich nehme an, dass "Wellen" das Subjekt dieses Satzes ist, weil das Verb "schlugen" in Pluralform steht und "Wellen" das einzige Pluralsubstantiv im Satz ist. Wenn ich mittlerweile die deutsche Grammatik richtig verstehe, muss alles, was vor dem Verb steht, irgendwie eine Einheit sein. Aber ich verstehe nicht, was in dieser ersten Position steht. Wäre die Bedeutung gleich mit:

> Als er [Grenouille] ein, Zwei Schritt zurück mit dem linkischen
> Zusammenklappen seines Körpers unter Baldinis Standpauke stand,
> schlugen genügend Wellen in der Luft...

?

(Ich verstehe auch nicht "ein, zwei Schritt" statt "ein, zwei Schritte," aber das ist für eine andere Zeit.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Der Satz ist tatsächlich etwas... eigenwillig konstruiert, aber deswegen nicht falsch.

"Wellen" ist hier nicht das Subjekt, sondern das Objekt. "(Hohe) Wellen schlagen" ist ein fester Ausdruck:

> Die missglückte Rede des Bürgermeisters schlug hohe Wellen in der Gemeinde.

Meist ist dieser Ausdruck bildlich gemeint, hier aber wird er wörtlich verwendet. Grenouilles Bewegungen sorgen für genügend Vermischung der Luft, für genügend "Wellen in der Luft", damit sich der Duft ausbreiten kann.

Was sind also Grenouilles Bewegungen? Er geht "ein, zwei Schritt zurück", und sein Körper klappt linkisch zusammen.

> Ein, zwei Schritt zurück, das linkische Zusammenklappen seines Körpers unter Baldinis Standpauke (...).

würde ich also als Auflistung verstehen. Eine vergleichbare Konstruktion wäre

> Der Hund, die Katze lagen auf dem Sofa.

Meist hat eine solche Liste ein Endglied, das mit "und" angeschlossen wird, aber das muss nicht der Fall sein.

Um die Frage, warum es "Schritt" und nicht "Schritte" heißt, gleich mit zu erledigen, es gibt im Deutschen viele mittlerweile veraltete Maßeinheiten, die sich an den Abmessungen des menschlichen Körpers orientieren. Ganz ähnlich wie im Englischen gab es "Fuß", "Elle" oder eben auch "Schritt" als Längenmaß.

Diese Maßeinheiten waren oft stark regional begrenzt, allein in und um Darmstadt beispielsweise gab es vor rund 200 Jahren drei unterschiedliche Varianten des "Darmstädter Fuß". Es kam auch vor, dass sich die Maßeinheiten tatsächlich an den Körpermaßen des jeweiligen Herrschers orientierten. Und wenn der alte Herzog starb und sein Sohn ihm nachfolgte, bekam die lokale Elle wieder eine neue Länge...

Jedenfalls geht Grenouille hier nicht "ein, zwei Schritte" zurück, sondern um die Strecke, die "ein, zwei Schritt" entsprechen - welche Variante der Längeneinheit "Schritt" auch immer gemeint ist.

Comment: "Der Hund, die Katze, alle lagen sie auf dem Sofa." - hier wird der Auflistungscharakter aber erheblich durch das eingeschobene "alle ... sie" erhöht. Vergleichbarer wäre mE "Der Hund, die Katze lagen auf dem Sofa."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Stimmt. Ich hatte den Satz zunächst bewusst etwas deutlicher formuliert, damit die Struktur gerade für Nicht-Muttersprachler und Lernende klarer wird, aber so ist es denke ich besser. Danke für den Hinweis.

Comment: Ich halte es tatsächlich für einen Fehler. Wieso sollten 1, 2 Schritt zurück (die ich auch nicht für ein Entfernungsmaß halte, sondern für 2 Schritte im Wortsinne) Wellen schlagen? "Das linkische Zusammenklappen seines Körpers schlug Wellen" dagegen funktioniert als Bild.